# Using icomoon icons inside ::before content property

Tags: html, css, svg, styled-components, icomoon

I'm using Icomoon icons to render icons in my application. It works great so far when I invoke them directly in tsx. The problem I encountered now is that I want to set my icon as a ::before content.

In my icomoon directory, Icomoon generates @font-face declaration in the style.css, like so:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?xxx');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?xxx#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?xxx') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?xxx') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?xxx#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

and then I have classes declarations, like:

```css
.icon-SomeIcon_ICO:before {
  content: "\e91f";
  color: #8898a9;
}
```

The icomoon also generates the svg file with glyphs that look like this:

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe91f;" glyph-name="SomeIcon" d="some path" />
```

Now, in my styled component, I'm trying to set that SomeIcon_ICO, as a content of the 3rd party library class, that I cannot alter directly:

```css
.ag-class-wrapper::before {
    content: '\e91f';
    color: #8898a9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 4px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

but the result is an actual \e91f being displayed on the page. Since most of the icomoon stuff is autogenerated, I don't have much control over it and there's not really any url to my custom icon that I could pass to the content property. For the record, I'm using styled-components as an additional layer but I don't think it may be helpful to get around my problem.

Is there a way to somehow use the icomoon icon as content?

Comment: _"but the result is an actual \e91f being displayed on the page"_ - then something must have transformed that CSS you have written, into something else, I suppose - because even without the font applied, this should render as a glyph, and not text: https://jsfiddle.net/qy46pj7o/

Comment: (If this got escaped into `content: '\\e91f'` perhaps(?), then it would indeed render as the _text_ `\e91f`.)

Comment: @CBroe yea, that's a good thinking. Now when I double escaped that (\\e91f), I actually get the glyph.. it's just not the icon I want but a blank glyph

Comment: Did you actually assign the font-family to the pseudo element as well?

Comment: @CBroe oh lord, I didn't. I'll gladly accept your first comment as a solution. The fact that the rendered result doesn't have \, has completely gone over my head, even though I literally wrote that the page displays simply `e91f`. The lack of font-family was a brain fart.